# noisy line between two specific points P5.js

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I'm trying to draw a noisy line (using perlin noise) between two specific points.
for example `A(100, 200)` and `B(400,600)`.
The line could be a points series.
Drawing random noisy line is so clear but I dont know how can I calculate distance specific points.
working of **P5.js.**
I don't have any code written yet to upload.
Please can anyone help me?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to ask questions. Also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to add sufficient comments that you would be able to learn how such a thing is done. There are a number of things that you should make yourself aware of if you aren't already, and it's hard to say which if these you're missing:

- for loops
- drawing lines using [`beginShape()`/`vertex()`/`endShape()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/beginShape)
- [Trigonometry](https://www.skillsyouneed.com/num/trigonometry.html) (in this case `sin`/`cos`/[`atan2`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/atan2)) which make it possible to find angles and determine 2d offsets in X and Y components at a given angle
- [`p5.Vector()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector) and its [`dist()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector/dist) function.

```js
// The level of detail in the line in number of pixels between each point.
const pixelsPerSegment = 10;
const noiseScale = 120;
const noiseFrequency = 0.01;
const noiseSpeed = 0.1;

let start;
let end;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  noFill();
  
  start = createVector(10, 10);
  end = createVector(380, 380);
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  
  let lineLength = start.dist(end);
  // Determine the number of segments, and make sure there is at least one.
  let segments = max(1, round(lineLength / pixelsPerSegment));
  // Determine the number of points, which is the number of segments + 1
  let points = 1 + segments;
  
  // We need to know the angle of the line so that we can determine the x
  // and y position for each point along the line, and when we offset based
  // on noise we do so perpendicular to the line.
  let angle = atan2(end.y - start.y, end.x - start.x);
  
  let xInterval = pixelsPerSegment * cos(angle);
  let yInterval = pixelsPerSegment * sin(angle);
  
  beginShape();
  // Always start with the start point
  vertex(start.x, start.y);
  
  // for each point that is neither the start nor end point
  for (let i = 1; i < points - 1; i++) {
    // determine the x and y positions along the straight line
    let x = start.x + xInterval * i;
    let y = start.y + yInterval * i;
    
    // calculate the offset distance using noice
    let offset =
      // The bigger this number is the greater the range of offsets will be
      noiseScale *
      (noise(
        // The bigger the value of noiseFrequency, the more erretically
        // the offset will change from point to point.
        i * pixelsPerSegment * noiseFrequency,
        // The bigger the value of noiseSpeed, the more quickly the curve
        // fluxuations will change over time.
        (millis() / 1000) * noiseSpeed
      ) - 0.5);
      
    // Translate offset into x and y components based on angle - 90°
    // (or in this case, PI / 2 radians, which is equivalent)
    let xOffset = offset * cos(angle - PI / 2);
    let yOffset = offset * sin(angle - PI / 2);
    
    vertex(x + xOffset, y + yOffset);
  }
  
  vertex(end.x, end.y);
  endShape();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

This code makes jaggy lines, but they could be smoothed using [`curveVertex()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/curveVertex). Also, making the line pass through the start and end points exactly is a little tricky because the very next point may be offset by a large amount. You could fix this by making `noiseScale` very depending on how far from an endpoint the current point is. This could be done by multiplying `noiseScale` by `sin(i / points.length * PI)` for example.